# Can method signature mismatch cause a crash at runtime?

Tags: c++

I have a runtime crash in a C++ code which is reproducible only when execute on a Solaris machine SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-27 and using Sun C 5.12 compiler and the the C++09 standard. It is not reproduced on Windows or Linux. One of the developers identified that the issue could be due to a signature mismatch between the hxx and the cxx file for a method. A test .so was created after matching the method signature and the crash went away.

The declaration in the hxx was:

```
string getAttributeList(void) const;
```

And the implementation in the cxx was:

```
string getAttributeList() const
{
}
```

Notice that there is no *void* in the cxx file. This was supposedly causing a crash. Later when the signatures were matched, by removing the *void* from the declaration, the crash went away.

I am not convinced that this was the reason for the crash as this should have been a compile time error. But since it built correctly without any error, can such a signature mismatch cause a runtime crash in C++?

Comment: What compiler  and c++ standard are you using?

Comment: In C++, an empty parameter list in a function declaration [is equivalent to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list) a parameter list of `void`.

Comment: Yes, it's shared object. Updated the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You should add part calling this function or actually a proper MCVE. const qualifier is not allowed on free functions so this code should not compile at all.

Comment: @VTT It did compile.

Comment: @MartinKahn: which compiler is it?

Comment: @P.W It is  Sun C 5.12 compiler and the the C++09 standard

Comment: Presumably the issue is elsewhere and the crash was fixed coincidentally by recompiling, the two declarations are identical